# Postgres can't figure out complex query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need some help with this very complex query. I am using postgresql. Here is the final results that I need:
- Group by company.id
- Group by mailers.mail_date
- Count the mailers
- Count the customer orders
- Count payments
- Show if there is a customer order
- Sum payments.payment_amt
- Sum clearinghouse_orders.remit

I am not sure how to embed the tables as shown in this image below:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a total newbie.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish EXCEPT I need to group the company so that the results are grouped first by Company and then Mail_date

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired resuls would really help explain what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for adding desired resulsts. Now please add sample data input. Then please show an attempt to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the left 3 tables with your diagram you can join them like this

```
select *
from companies 
inner join dbas ON companies.id = dbas.company_id
inner join mailers ON dbas.id = mailers.dba_id
```

to get "*results are grouped first by Company and then Mail_date*" add a GROUP BY clause to the query listing those columns and include those columns  the ELECT clause too.

```
SELECT
  companies.id, companies.name, mailers.mail_date
from companies 
inner join dbas ON companies.id = dbas.company_id
inner join mailers ON dbas.id = mailers.dba_id
GROUP BY
  companies.id, companies.name, mailers.mail_date
```

Now when it gets down to payments (for example) things can get tricky because you want to get those summed accurately. If not all companies will have orders you need to use a LEFT JOIN now, and for calculating the sum of payments I suggest you do those sums BEFORE joining to other tables, like this:

```
SELECT
  companies.id, companies.name, mailers.mail_date, SUM(p.payment_amt)
from companies 
inner join dbas ON companies.id = dbas.company_id
inner join mailers ON dbas.id = mailers.dba_id

left join customer_orders ON dbas.id = customer_orders.dba_id
left join (
           select customer_order_id, SUM(payment_amt) as payment_amt
           from payments
           group by customer_order_id
          ) p on customer_orders.id = p.customer_order_id
GROUP BY
  companies.id, companies.name, mailers.mail_date
```

You have much more logic to include in your final query than is included here, but hopefully it gets you started.